# How to design the database in this use case?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Let say I have an application called `ReportGenerator`, it allows user to have input how many fields, and the fields value. For example, they can have a `jobApplicationReport`, so, they can define several fields like this:`jobTitle`, `expectedSalary`.

so, in the DB, I will have something like this:
Table Name: `UserReport` and have these fields: `id`,`title`,`fields`.

And the data will like this:
`1`,`jobApplicationReport`,`jobTitle,expectedSalary`

and also, I have a `UserReportData` have fields, `id`,`userReportId`,`value`
and the data will like this:
`1`,`1`,`jobTitle:programmer,expectedSalary:200K`

`2`,`1`,`jobTitle:projectManager,expectedSalary:400K`

So, my question is, the `value` fields in the `UserReportData` seems to be very stupid, because it can't take full advantage of the SQL database, also can't use the index to increase the performance.

I may think one other solution is that I can create one more table, when user add a new report. In this example, I may not have the abstract `UserReportData` table, instead, having a `UserReportData_jobApplicationReport` table. And have as many fields I want.

But a single user may have many reports, so, my database will have LOTS of tables. Any solutions to deal with this problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an extra table for report_fields:
`report_id,field_id,value`
and on for the fields:
`field_id,name`

So in fields you'll have:

```
1, jobTitle
2, expectedSalary
```

and your report_fields:

```
1,1,programmer
1,2,200k
2,1,projectManager
2,1,400k
```